# Find the smallest angle in the triangle

Tags: geometry

> The point H is the orthocenter of the triangle ABC and the point C is the centroid of the triangle ABH. In that case the smallest angle of the triangle ABC is: (60), (30), (45), ($\angle ACB$)?

This is actually quite tough. I got that the orthocenter is the meeting of all of the altitudes, but I still can't figure this out.

And $c$ is the median of $\triangle ABH$. I don't see anyway to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$ABH$ is an equilateral triangle, $C$ is its center, so $H$ is the orthocenter of $ABC$.

So the smallest angle of $ABC$ is $30°$.

[image]

Comment: Hi, (+1) good answer. But how did you devise that $ABH$ is equilateral>

Comment: A bit of intuition, confirmed by the possible known answers.

Comment: Do we need it to be equilateral? If the orthocenter is outside we already know $\triangle ABC$ is obtuse. Hence, $\angle C > 90$, so, we could have an arrangement of $30, 59, 91$ right?

Comment: But in this case $C$ is not the centroid of $ABH$.

Comment: Wait, how is it not?

Comment: Intuitively: if $C$ is near to $90°$ than $F$ is near to $C$ but the midpoints of $AH$ and $BH$ are not near to $C$ so the intersection of the two medians cannot be $C$ ( use pencil and paper and you can easily see).

Answer (score 1):

Using 
$$\vec{AH}=\frac{\tan B\vec{AB}+\tan C\vec{AC}}{\tan A+\tan B+\tan C},$$
(see the answer for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1441969/pa2-sin-apb2-sin-bpc2-sin-c-is-minimum-if-p-is-the-incenter)) we have
$$\vec{AC}=\frac{\vec{AB}+\vec{AH}}{3}$$
$$\Rightarrow \vec{AC}=\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{\tan B}{3(\tan A+\tan B+\tan C)}\right)\vec{AB}+\frac{\tan AC}{3(\tan A+\tan B+\tan C)}\vec{AC}.$$

Hence, we have
$$0=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{\tan B}{3(\tan A+\tan B+\tan C)}\quad\text{and}\quad 1=\frac{\tan C}{3(\tan A+\tan B+\tan C)},$$
i.e.
$$0=\tan A+2\tan B+\tan C\quad\text{and}\quad 3\tan A+3\tan B+2\tan C=0,$$
i.e.
$$\tan A=\tan B=a,\tan C=-3a\ \text{for some $a$}$$

Since it is known that $$\tan A+\tan B+\tan C=\tan A\tan B\tan C$$for $A+B+C=\pi$ (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477364/prove-that-tan-a-tan-b-tan-c-tan-a-tan-b-tan-c-abc-180-circ)), we have
$$a+a-3a=-3a^3.$$
Hence, $a=\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$ gives $A=B=30^\circ, C=120^\circ.$

Answer (score 0):

See triangleabh is equilateral hence abc has orthocentre  h hence smallest angle is 30 degrees