# How to prove that $PA^2\sin A + PB^2 \sin B + PC^2 \sin C$ takes the same value for all points P on the incircle of the triangle $\triangle ABC$.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

> Prove that $PA^2\sin A + PB^2 \sin B + PC^2 \sin C$ takes the same value for all points P on the incircle of the triangle $\triangle ABC$.

[image]

The previous part asks that

> If I is the incentre of the $\triangle ABC$ and $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ are respectively the angles $BIC$, $CIA$ and $AIB$, prove that $$\frac{a \cdot IA}{\sin \alpha} = \frac{b \cdot IB}{\sin \beta} = \frac{c \cdot IC}{\sin \gamma}$$

And I have solve it with trigonometry, but I am not sure how to use it to prove the first statement. The general problem can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1441969/pa2-sin-apb2-sin-bpc2-sin-c-is-minimum-if-p-is-the-incenter) but I wonder if there is a simpler solution here since it only asks for points on the incircle. An idea is to use the fact that $$PA^2 \sin A = PA \cdot NL$$
etc. But I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Presumably $LMN$ is the pedal triangle of $P$?

Comment: @user10354138 Yes

Comment: Do you accept a proof using vectors as an answer to your question?

Comment: @YNK sure if it is any simpler compared to the linked answer.

Comment: One of the answers in the linked reference, I am sure you know which one,  proves that the statement in question is a minimum when $P$ coincides with the incenter.  But it also contains everything one needs to prove the statement in your question. I thought of showing you that by elaborating (expanding and simplifying) certain parts of that answer. Now, I know that that is not what you need. So, I am not posting anything.